# Can I hide commas from a JSX bug using custom CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsx

One component of my website is based on the following .js code:

```
 items.add( 
     `field-${field.id()}`, 
     <div className="Mason-Field Form-group"> 
         <label> 
             {field.icon() ? <>{icon(field.icon())} </> : null} 
             {field.name()} 
         </label> 
         ,<div className="FormControl Mason-Inline-Answers">{answer_list}</div>, 
     </div> 
 );
```

In the website, the  commas are literally in the JSX just like they appear in the output. This must be an oversight when the hyperscript was converted to JSX. See the following test post screenshot.

I personally am not able to fix this in the .js level. Is there a way to hide the commas in the CSS level?

[Test pose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4HZm.png)

Answer (score 0):

The approach is to set the font color of the outer div to transparent and then set it again on the children:

```
.Mason-Field.Form-group { color: transparent }
.Mason-Field.Form-group > * { color: initial }
```

Depending on your other classes `FormControl` and `Mason-Inline-Answers`, you might need to be more specific.